# How to count character in a string by group in r?

Tags: r, string, count

I have a data frame that looks like the following.

```
ID<-c('001','002','003','004','005')
TYPE<-c('ABB','BCC','AAA','BBA','BCC')
Group<-c('1','2','2','2','1')
df<-data.frame(ID,TYPE,Group)
df

   ID TYPE Group
1 001  ABB     1
2 002  BCC     2
3 003  AAA     2
4 004  BBA     2
5 005  BCC     1
```

I want to get a table to know the frequency of each character in each group and its percentage.

```
      Group 
      1    2 
A     1    4
B     3    3
C     2    2
Total 6    9
```

And the percentage of it

```
       Group 
       1       2 
A      0.17    0.44
B      0.50    0.33
C      0.33    0.22
Total% 1.00    1.00
```

I try the following, but it shows error.

```
str_count(df$TYPE[(df$Group==1], pattern = "A")
str_count(df$TYPE[(df$Group==2], pattern = "A")
str_count(df$TYPE[(df$Group==1], pattern = "B")
str_count(df$TYPE[(df$Group==2], pattern = "B")
str_count(df$TYPE[(df$Group==1], pattern = "C")
str_count(df$TYPE[(df$Group==2], pattern = "C")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about in base with `stack` and `table`:

```
tbl <- table(stack(`names<-`(strsplit(df$TYPE, ""), df$Group)))
#      ind
#values 1 2
#     A 1 4
#     B 3 3
#     C 2 2
```

Then we can add percentages:

```
round(prop.table(tbl, 2), 2)
#      ind
#values    1    2
#     A 0.17 0.44
#     B 0.50 0.33
#     C 0.33 0.22
```

If you would like sums:

```
addmargins(tbl, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But it shows "Error in strsplit(df$TYPE, "") : non-character argument"...

Comment: You have class factor. Check `class(df$TYPE)`. You mistakenly coded the variable as factor. You should use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you are not using the variable as a categorical variable for modeling.

Comment: @TerenceTien You can use `as.character` to fix that, `strsplit(as.character(df$Type), "")`

Comment: You should recode from the beginning instead of adding marginal fixes, take care of it from the start. (Not a knock against M. Lundberg btw)

Comment: my 2c: using `setNames`  would have a bit clearer intent `table(stack(setNames(strsplit(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise(TYPE = unlist(strsplit(TYPE, ""))) %>% 
       group_by(Group, TYPE) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>% spread(Group, Count)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#
#    TYPE     1     2
#   (chr) (int) (int)
# 1     A     1     4
# 2     B     3     3
# 3     C     2     2
```

To get the percentage count:

```
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise(TYPE = unlist(strsplit(TYPE, ""))) %>% 
       group_by(Group, TYPE) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
       spread(Group, Count) %>%  mutate_each(funs(round(./sum(.), 2)), -TYPE)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# 
#    TYPE     1     2
#   (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1     A  0.17  0.44
# 2     B  0.50  0.33
# 3     C  0.33  0.22
```

Comment: You can simplify: `df %>% separate_rows(TYPE, sep = '\\B') %>% count(TYPE, Group) %>% spread(Group, n) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate_each(funs(prop.table), -TYPE)`

Comment: @alistaire Where does the function `separate_rows` come from?

Comment: It was [a recent addition to `tidyr`](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Comment: @alistaire Excellent! Thanks for the comment. Get something new to play with. But anyway, I think table is still the way to go here.